# IEnumerable contract, should I check for GetEnumerator returning null?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Is it safe to assume that `GetEnumerator()` always return not null?

Comment: Consider changing the title of your post such that `Yes` would be the answer to both the title **and** the body of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is usually safe to assume that. If `GetEnumerator` returns `null` this can be considered a bug in the implementation. The IL generated for a `foreach` loop does not perform the check either. So the burden is on the `IEnumerable`, not on its consumer.

Comment: *IL generated for a foreach* Even if it checked, it would throw a `NullPointerException`... the same that will be throwed when accessing `.MoveNext()`